# Why is <= throwing an invalid syntax error in Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am very new to Python.
I'm trying to create a loop that compares int, between a range.

```
while counter < N:
     x = randn()
     if x >= 0 and <=1:
        print('0-1')
        counter = counter + 1

     elif x < 0 and < -1
        print("0- -1")

    counter = counter + 1
```

I keep getting a syntax error on the *<=*

```
  File "<ipython-input-35-1d74b6e80ea0>", line 9
if x >= 0 and <=1:
               ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Any help on what I am missing would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `0 <= x <= 1` is what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
if x >= 0 and x <= 1:
```

The reason for your confusion is because you're writing it out as you would explain it to a person. X has to larger or equal to zero and smaller or equal to one.

In python however, these are two separate *conditions*, which need to be written out in full: `x >= 0` and also `x <= 1`.

*Alternatively*, you have the option of combining the operators into a single condition like so:

```
if 0 <= x <= 1
```

Merging them this way turns the inequality into a single (compound) condition.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, its fixed!

Answer (score -1):

You should try writing it as `if x >= 0 and x <= 1:`. The `and` connects two separate statements, so you need to write the comparisons separately.